# R- yearqtr data xts, access single quarters

Tags: r, xts

I have an xts objects which is yearqtr (1990 Q1 2012 Q3). I want to work with the data going up to 2011 Q3. I tried several things:

```
data["1990::2011:3"]
data["1990/2012-3"]
```

The 3 is treated like monthly, so if i use

```
data["1990::2012:9]
data["1990/2012-9]
```

I get the third quarter. However, this is inconvenient. I would like to have the third quarter, whenever i put a three in the brackats. How would I write this ?

Best regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subset`

```
subset(data, index(data) >= as.yearqtr('1995 Q1') & index(data) <= as.yearqtr('2011 Q1')  )
```

or just normal subset using `[ ]`

```
data[index(data) >= as.yearqtr('2000 Q1') &  index(data) <= as.yearqtr('2011 Q1') ]
```

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied with any of the answer, you should upvote it and mark it accepted.  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  data["1990::2011:x"]
```

Where x = 7 or 8 or 9 : they give all the same result.

Here an example

```
x <- as.yearqtr(1990 + seq(0, 4*(2013-1990))/4)
zz <- xts(rnorm(length(x)),x, frequency = 4)
as.ts(zz["1990::2011:9"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. This works of course, but I get the information on which time period of the data I need in the format 2012 Q1 as string. I would like to manipulate this string, such that I can get the according horizon.  It seems inconvenient to transform Q1 into 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: you can do this for example..`zz[paste('1990',as.Date(as.yearqtr("2012 Q3")),sep='::')]`